# Using jQuery UI Slider dynamically?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I have a jQuery UI slider in which if the user types numbers into the input element the slider moves appropriately.

```
$("#slider-range-min").slider({
            range: "min",
            value: 1,
            step: 1000,
            min: 0,
            max: 5000000,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("input").val(ui.value);
            }
        });
        $("input").change(function (event) {
            var value1 = $("input").val();
            $("#slider-range-min").slider("option", "value", value1);
        });
```

But what i need is i want the slider to be in the middle whatever value i enter in the text box for the first time and then if i move the slider rightside means my value in the textbox has to increase and for leftside it has to decrease without setting these minimum and maximum values..

Any suggestion?

EDIT: what i need is when i enter 500 in the textbox my slider has to move to the center automatically..if i move the slider rightside the end must be 1000 and for leftside it must be 0 and if i enter 400 slider must move to center position automatically and the rightside end must be 800 and leftside 0

Comment: can you show an example of what you mean? perhaps some html? so I can see how it looks?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/MD3mX/

Comment: @Antimated:what i need is when i enter 500 in the textbox my slider has to move to the center..if i move the slider rightside the end must be 1000 and for leftside it must be 0

Comment: and for 400 the rightside end must be 800 and leftside 0

Comment: @Antimated:got my point?

Comment: yeah I've got the point :) I was testing some things, but then I saw someone posted a solution :). sorry I couldn't help u :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what you need is to basically change the slider range from 0 to double whatever is entered in the text box? I think you can use the method "option" on the slider such as:

```
 $("input").change(function (event) {
     var value1 = parseFloat($("input").val());
     var highVal = value1 * 2;
     $("#slider-range-min").slider("option", {"max": highVal, "value": value1});
 });
```

Edit: here's a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/cXYC4/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but this might work: http://flowplayer.org/tools/rangeinput/